# gatsby-remark-katex plugin in my Gatsby blog is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby, katex

I want to be able to render Math equations in my Gatsy blog both in inline mode & display mode.

I write my blogs using Markdown.

I installed the `gatsby-remark-katex` plugin by folling the instructions at the following link: [gatsby-remark-katex](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-katex/)

Essentially there are three steps:

**STEP-1:** Install `gatsby-transformer-remark` `gatsby-remark-katex` `katex`
I have not made any mistake in installation. I see these packages in my `package.json` file.

**STEP-2:** Add the following code snippet in `gatsby.config.js`.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-remark-katex`,
  options: {
    strict: `ignore`,
  },
},
```

After I added the above code snippet, my `gatsby.config.js` looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: { title: "Hemanta Sundaray - Full-stack JavaScript Engineer" },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        trackingIds: ["UA-180842449-2"],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "src",
        path: `${__dirname}/src`,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-katex`,
            options: {
              strict: `ignore`,
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-reading-time`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-code-titles`,
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-vscode`,
            options: {
              theme: `SynthWave '84`,
              extensions: ["synthwave-vscode"],
              inlineCode: {
                marker: ".",
              },
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 800,
              quality: 100,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-table-of-contents`,
            options: {
              exclude: "Table of Contents",
              // tight: false,
              // ordered: false,
              fromHeading: 2,
              toHeading: 4,
              className: "table-of-contents",
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-autolink-headers`,
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Have I made any mistake in this step?

**STEP-3:** Add KATEX CSS to your template.

My `gatsby.browser.js` file looks like the following after adding the KATEX CSS.

```
import "./src/styles/global.css"
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css"
```

Is `gatsby.browser.js` the right file in which Katex CSS needs to be added?

I also tried adding the Katex CSS in the `index.js` file; however the output was not as expected.

After following the above-mentioned 3 steps, I tested the following markdown:

```
Example: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
```

However, Math equation did not render correctly:

I received the following output:

```
Example: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in step 3.

You need to add `import "katex/dist/katex.min.css"` in the same file where you build your blog-post component starting from the markdown file.

The one file where you probably do something like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}`